# Django: update modal without form without overwrite database

Tags: ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

I need to update a django model using 3 bootstrap modals. I use AJAX requests to modify this values.

In every step I modify one field, but users can cancel de process so I only want to save changes into db when they confirm the action in the last modal.

How can I do this without using forms? Only **model.field = new_value** syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to do that but the best solution depends from your application and further development plan. In any case you need to create a new url and view to update your model. Then you can hit this url with ajax and retrieve updated value.

Code below is just an illustration

```
url(r'^modal-answer/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<value>[-\w]+)/$', my_view, name="modal-answer"),


import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request, id, value):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # find your obj and update
        data = {} # populate data dict with useful values
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about data dict in AJAX requests.